# PHP keyword search

Tags: php, cassandra

I am building search system, with `nosql` database `cassandra` and it doesn't support any kind of keyword search, so there is a few options, and after some searching this is what came up with.

I could store list of keywords that could be searched, for example let's say it's a music genres. So i would store all of those genres and then retrieve all of them at once and filter them with php, would it be very slow with let's say `2k` keywords or more?

I would like to get filtered results in somewhere `~100ms` is that possible? If so what kind of `php` functions would help me with word filtering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to filter songs or albums by music genres, that's actually really easy to do with Cassandra.  I'll use the term 'tag' instead of genre, since you could really do this with any kind of tag, not just genres.

Lay out a column family where the keys are tags and the rows have one cell for each item that has that tag.  You can use the item name or ID for the cell names, and the cell values can be empty or hold any other metadata you'd like.

Using phpcassa (which is based on the original Thrift RPC API for Cassandra), if you want to store an item under a tag, it would be as simple as this:

```
 $cf->insert($tag, array($item->name, $item->metadata));
```

To fetch all items that have a particular tag, do:

```
$cf->get($tag);
```

Although a good PHP CQL 3 driver isn't complete yet, with CQL 3 you could do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TAGS (
    tag utf8,
    itemid uuid,
    PRIMARY KEY (tag, itemid)
);
```

You would add a tagged item like so:

```
INSERT INTO TAGS (tag, itemid) values ("rock", "Led Zeppelin");
```

And you could fetch all items with a tag by doing:

```
SELECT * FROM TAGS WHERE tag="rock";
```

You could easily store a million items under a single tag, and fetching the first, say, 2000, would be very fast, only a handful of milliseconds.

Comment: You didn't understand what i need. Yes your answer would be correct if i would search for a `full` word, but i need to search while user types that tag, so say user typed `beat` instead of `Beatles` i would need to find closest tags which in this case is most likely going to be `Beatles` and few others that are close to what user typed in

Comment: Well never mind i did it in even more interesting way with column slices, and so far it seems to be working quite nicely